# this vs $scope in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm developing a rails app with angular, and in the past, I had been using $scope to access variables and methods of the angular's controllers. 
After watching the Shaping up with Angular.js course at codeschool, I realized that the usage of **this** and the alias of controllers are a better way of accessing them.

Anyway, my app works fine with $scope but when I change to the "**this**" implementation, the laboratories var came empty...

I let some code here:
html:

```
<div ng-controller="LaboratorioController as labCtrl">
          <tr ng-repeat="laboratorio in labCtrl.laboratorios" >
            <td>{{ laboratorio.nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ laboratorio.razon_social }}</td>
            <td>{{ laboratorio.direccion }}</td>
```

angular code:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('guiaV', []);
    app.controller('LaboratorioController', function( $http) {
      this.laboratorios = [];
      return $http.get('./laboratorios.json').success(function(data) {
        return this.laboratorios = data;
      });
    });
})();
```

any idea?

Comment: @Blackhole i have already seen that answer and doesnt help me...

Comment: So here is a good tip: use `$scope`. Really.

Comment: Having a similar question "title" as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers doesn"t make it necessarily a duplicate ... fast reviewers should also read content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you put into `angular.controller` is used as a constructor. JavaScript constructors that return nothing, implicitly return `this`. If a constructor returns another object, then this object is supposed to be the new object. e.g.:

```
function Class1() {
    this.prop = 'xxx';
}
var obj1 = new Class1();
console.log(obj1.prop); // prints 'xxx'

function Class2() {
    this.prop = 'xxx';
    return {
        hooray: 'yyy'
    };
}
var obj2 = new Class2();
console.log(obj2.prop); // prints undefined
console.log(obj2.hooray); // prints 'yyy'
```

Your controller returns an http promise (the return value of `$http.get(...).success(...)`), so angular believes that this (the http promise) is your actual controller (the thing it assigns to `$scope.labCtrl`).

No time to test it, hope I got it right.

Tiny example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ylz5oqOQgoWTIH9KVILA?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

You assigned a value to `this.laboratorios` inside a closure. Remember that its scope is separated from the outer scope. `this` applies to something completely different. This is why using `$scope` is more reliable (and readable, if you ask my personal opinion). You might want to bind the closure to a `this` value:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('guiaV', []);
    app.controller('LaboratorioController', function( $http) {
      this.laboratorios = [];
      $http.get('./laboratorios.json').success(function(data) {
        return this.laboratorios = data;
      }.bind(this));
    });
})();
```

Alternatively, you can use a variable that will be available from both scopes:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('guiaV', []);
    app.controller('LaboratorioController', function( $http) {
      this.laboratorios = [];
      var foo = this;
      $http.get('./laboratorios.json').success(function(data) {
        return foo.laboratorios = data;
      });
    });
})();
```

Comment: [Really no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers). Inside a controller, `this` isn't `$scope`.

Comment: @Blackhole You are not helping. Really.

Comment: @nilsK What is unclear? `this` isn't `$scope`, and detailed explanations are in the link.

Comment: My dear insightful @Blackhole, please indicate where in my answer do I say that `this` and `$scope` are the same thing? I fail to see such an affirmation.

Comment: In your code: you're using `this.laboratorios`. Twice.

Comment: I think `return` before `$http.get ...` has to go and - as far as i understand - it will work fine

Comment: No, I'm showing the OP how to assign a value to `this.laboratorios` inside a closure he used as the `$http` success callback.

Comment: @KosProv Yes, I missed that. I edited the answer to contain working code. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @mingos. Yep. So you're solving only one of the two problems of the OP, right?

Comment: You decided to downvote my answer, nitpick in the comments and make a noise about the answer being a dupe instead of just pointing the complete answer. I decided to help as much as I could.

Comment: Blackhole we are part of stackoverflow to help other developers, if you dont want to, please delete your account. Thanks @mingos, thats the attitude that a community of developers looks for.

Comment: you sir, are a master. Thanks a lot, you don't just resolve my error, you teach me the way and the difference. I flag this question in order to get back the erronous "duplicate".